# Mysql Ошибка "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Tags: mysql

У меня есть простой запрос в базу

```
UPDATE users SET username='test' WHERE id='3'
```

После этого запрос зависает на 120 секунд и появлееться ошибка "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction". Это касается только одного пользователя, во всех других случаях все хорошо

Командой `show full processlist;` убил все апдейты которые зависли к этому юзеру и вновь запустил этот апдейт и все равно то же.

Как мне разлочить его?

Comment: удалось как-то решить?

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear ,  помог только рестарт базы.

Comment: Вы перед этим не где не стартуете транзакцию вручную? `START TRANSACTION;`

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае, если подождать несколько секунд (для этого в `php` есть функция `sleep`) и потом запустить опять запрос, то всё идёт нормально.

А если тоже возникает ошибка, ждём ещё, пока не получиться.